# Intercept TouchUpInside event in UITableView while tableview scrolls

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm building out a UITableView that has a button in the tableview's section header, so that as the user scrolls down the screen, the button is pinned to the top of the screen.

The problem is that the **touch events for the section header's button don't register when the UITableView is moving**. The button only gets the touch event if the tableview is not scrolling.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (!_sectionHeaderView) {
        _sectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];

        UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
        [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upArrow"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(scrollToTop:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_sectionHeaderView addSubview:backButton];

    }
    return _sectionHeaderView;
}
```

Currently, what happens is:
- If the tableview is not scrolling, the button performs as you'd expect: tap it, and the button gets the TouchUpInside gesture.
- If the tableview is scrolling, the button doesn't get the TouchUpInside gesture - instead, the tableview just stops in place.

I've tried subclassing the UITableView and looking at the touchesBegan: methods, etc and that didn't work. I see the same pattern: the gestures only show up if/when the tableview isn't moving.

**Update:**
This isn't a usability issue - while I can't show screenshots of the design I'm working on, it's a valid use case to use buttons & controls in the section header.

Here's a quick sketch to explain why:

[image: Floating section header]

Comment: This would cause a bad user experience, as @Undo already mentioned and I strongly recommend against this.

Comment: @Stunner I've updated the question with an image to clarify the user experience

Comment: Ah I see... that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out! All you need to do is subclass `UITableView`, and override `hitTest:withEvent:`

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([[super hitTest:point withEvent:event] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *buttonThatWasTapped = (UIButton *)[super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
        [buttonThatWasTapped sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
        return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Here's what this code does: if the tableview is touched, and the touch occurred in the bounds of a UIButton, the tableview will forward the touch event to the UIButton.

There's a caveat here: the touch event may get sent to the UIButton several times (I'm seeing the call being made 3 times for each touch). This code was sufficient for my needs, but if you're using this code in your app, watch out for that issue - you may have to modify the above code to account for this.

Answer (score 2):

### This is what's supposed to happen.

The user is used to this behavior - it allows them to stop the table view's scrolling when they see what they wanted to touch.

Imagine I was scrolling through a table looking for the row 'unicorns', and I was scrolling *really fast* (because it's a big table, and I'm not sure where unicorns is). When 'unicorns' crosses my vision, I will instinctively stop the table to select it.

With the current system, I can tap anywhere on the table view and it will stop. If table views were implemented your way, I would tap 'underground rockchucks' to stop the table, and all of a sudden I am looking at information about rockchucks - and I want information about Unicorns.

I now become a disgruntled user, return your app to Apple, and get my $0.99 back.

You don't want users doing that.

Comment: This design doesn't have a HIG issue - I've got a single UITableView section, so the section header is always floating at the top of the screen. While I appreciate the feedback, it's not applicable to my design.